# VC-dimension of the class of hypotheses that assign label $1$ to exactly $k$ points of some finite domain $\mathcal{X}$

Tags: machine-learning, binary-classification, vc-theory

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a finite domain and $k$ a number such that $k\leq|\mathcal{X}|$. Consider the hypothesis class

$\mathcal{H}:=\big\{h:|\{\mathbf{x}\in\mathcal{X}:h(\mathbf{x})=1\}|=k\bigr\}$;

that is, the class of hypotheses $h:\mathcal{X}\to\{0,1\}$ that assign label $1$ to exactly $k$ elements of $\mathcal{X}$.

**Question:** What is the VC-dimension of $\mathcal{H}$?

(Note that this is Exercise 6.2 (1) in the book "Understanding Machine Learning: From Theory to Algorithms" from Shalev-Shwartz & Ben-David.)

The claim is that $\mathrm{VCdim}(\mathcal{H})=\min\{k,|\mathcal{X}|-k\}$. The solution that was provided to me proceeds as follows:

1. Show that $\mathrm{VCdim}(\mathcal{H})\leq\min\{k,|\mathcal{X}|-k\}$.
2. Show that $\mathrm{VCdim}(\mathcal{H})\geq\min\{k,|\mathcal{X}|-k\}$.

I'm already struggling with the first part. Let $C\subseteq\mathcal{X}$ be a set of size $k+1$. Then, $C$ is not shattered by $\mathcal{H}$ as there is no $h\in\mathcal{H}$ satisfying $h(\mathbf{x})=1$ for all $\mathbf{x}\in C$ $\Rightarrow\;\mathrm{VCdim}(\mathcal{H})\leq k$. On the other hand, if $C\subseteq\mathcal{X}$ is of size $|\mathcal{X}|-k+1$, then $C$ is not shattered by $\mathcal{H}$ as there is no $h\in\mathcal{H}$ satisfying $h(\mathbf{x})=0$ for all $\mathbf{x}\in C$. Hence, $\mathrm{VCdim}(\mathcal{H})\leq\min\{k,|\mathcal{X}|-k\}$.

I don't see why the second step in this line of reasoning is true. For example, consider some domain of cardinality $|\mathcal{X}|=4$ and let $k=3$. Then, $|\mathcal{X}|-k+1=2$. So when I pick any $2$ instances from $\mathcal{X}$ so that $C=\{\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2\}$, why is there no $h\in\mathcal{H}$ satisfying $h(\mathbf{x}_1)=h(\mathbf{x}_2)=0$? In my opinion, as $2<k=3$, this is actually the only possible labeling.

I am convinced the general claim is correct but I believe the proof of the upper bound in the form above is incomplete. Or did I completely misunderstand the problem setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, there is no such $h$. Every $h$ assigns 1 to three elements of the four, so can only assign 0 to one element.

Comment: This is the obvious part to me. If $C\subseteq\mathcal{X}$ is of size $k+1$, then there must be at least one element that is labeled as 0 $\Rightarrow\,\mathrm{VCdim}(\mathcal{H})\leq k$. Next step is to show that also $\mathrm{VCdim}(\mathcal{H})\leq |\mathcal{X}|-k$. So in the proof that I found it is argued that if $C\subseteq\mathcal{X}$ is of size $|\mathcal{X}|-k+1$ that no $h\in\mathcal{H}$ exists that assigns label $0$ to every $\mathbf{x}\in C$. This is what my example is about. It shows there is such $h$ (maybe it is just a typo in the proof that I found, I don't know).

Comment: @VK88 my answer is addressing the $|\mathcal{X}|-k$ case. There is no such $h\in \mathcal{H}$. Perhaps being more concrete will help: in your example, you wanted $h(x_1)=h(x_2)=0$; what values do you propose for $h(x_3)$ and $h(x_4)$? Remember you had $|\mathcal{X}|=4$ and $k=3$.

Comment: In case $|\mathcal{X}|=4$ and $k=3$, any set $C\subseteq\mathcal{X}$ of size $|\mathcal{X}|-k+1$ has only two elements $x_1$ and $x_2$. Hence, the labeling $h(x_1)=h(x_2)=1$ is not possible by any $h\in\mathcal{H}$, which is why $C$ is not shattered. But this is in contrast to the claim in the proof that I found that says there is no $h\in\mathcal{H}$ satisfying $h(x_1)=h(x_2)=0$. The latter is in my opinion the only labeling that is possible for this two element set. But maybe this is just a typo and they meant $=1$ instead $=0$.

Comment: @VK88 I think $h(x_1)=h(x_2)=1$ is possible, with $h(x_3)=1$ and $h(x_4)=0$.  But $h(x_1)=h(x_2)=0$ is not possible.  ?

Comment: I think $C$ has only two elements (i.e., $|\mathcal{X}|-k+1=4-3+1=2$ is the size of $C$). Hence, there are no $x_3$ and $x_4$ in $C$. Only $x_1$ and $x_2$. And I want to show that $C$ is not shattered by $\mathcal{H}$.

Comment: @VK88 those are the only elements of $C$, but $h$ is a function from $\mathcal{X}$, which has four elements. Shattering $C$ means there is an $h\in\mathcal{H}$ achieving each pattern of 0s and 1s on $C$. You can achieve the patterns 01 (with 0111), 10 (1011), and 11 (1101), but not 00.

Comment: Oh, the penny has dropped! Of course, $h:\mathcal{X}\to\{0,1\}$ not $C\to\{0,1\}$. I've confused $\mathcal{H}$ with $\mathcal{H}_C$, where the latter is the restriction of $\mathcal{H}$ to $C$. The definition of shattering I'm aware of is "A class $\mathcal{H}$ shatters a finite set $C\subset\mathcal{X}$ if the restriction of $\mathcal{H}$ to $C$ is the set of all functions from $C$ to $\{0,1\}$ (book of Shalev-Schwartz & Ben-David). But the line of reasoning in my original post refers directly to $\mathcal{H}$ instead of  $\mathcal{H}_C$. Thanks a lot for helping me out!